# android application is opening a browser application instead of a webView, how do I stop that?

Tags: java, android, url, webview, webviewclient

Right now when I push a specific button it starts an intent to open a web page into a webView, but instead it opens a Browser Application, revealing the address bar which is not what I want.

After doing some research I found out I can use the shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method to stop this from happening and just open the page in a webView, but I don't know how to implement this method in my code, help would be greatly appreciated!

This is what I have in the class where I'm opening the web page:

```
public class Codes extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.codes);

    View titleView = getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    if (titleView != null) {
      ViewParent parent = titleView.getParent();
      if (parent != null && (parent instanceof View)) {
        View parentView = (View)parent;
        parentView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(228, 108, 10));
      }
    }

    WebView codes = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.codesWebView);
    codes.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    codes.loadUrl("http://dev10.affirmaconsulting.com:24009/keyentry");
    shouldOverrideUrlLoading(codes, "http://dev10.affirmaconsulting.com:24009/keyentry");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do this exact task in one of our activities and haven't ran into this issue.  Here is what ours looks like:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.document_viewer_activity);

    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.documentViewerWebview);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    String url = getString(R.string.document_viewer_url) + 
            getIntent().getExtras().getString("media");
    wv.loadUrl(url);

}
```

With the webview defined in the layout file looking like this:

```
  <WebView
        android:id="@+id/documentViewerWebview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 />
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem, that pages were not loading in my webview but instead via the browser application. I resolved the issue by implementing a WebViewClient class and overriding the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method.

```
    WebViewClient webClient = new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url)
        {
            return false;
        }
    };
    webView.setWebViewClient(webClient);
```

The following link proved to be helpful:
http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/08/05/override-url-loading-in-webview-android-tutorial/